# The best way to guess the needed data using Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I have a question, which is not entirely related to *Mathematica*, and would appreciate any help on this matter.

I have the following dataset, which shows the growth of a bacterium in a specific medium:

```
data = {{0, Around[0.974286, 0.288609]}, {3, Around[0.491667, 0.165076]}, {6, Around[0.829444, 0.404031]}, 
        {17, Around[0.2075, 0.191127]}, {19, Around[0.137692, 0.0961902]}, {22, Around[0.199412, 0.241207]}, 
        {24, Around[0.0893333, 0.0359497]}};


ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 17, 19, 22, 24}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

I need the data for the time points: $t = 9$ h, $15$ h, $18$ h, and $21$ h. This experiment was done years ago, and it's not possible to repeat it to obtain the values for the mentioned time points. Is there a method or approach in *Mathematica*'s tool kit to provide some, at least naive, guesses for these values?

Comment: Do you have a model by which you think bacteria populations grow?  Like, it's exponential, or logistic, or goverened by some differential equation?  Otherwise there's probably not much more to do that linear interpolation.

Comment: More details about the measurements would be helpful (although dealing with that makes your question more a appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com).  For example, are the sampling efforts identical for each time period?  Same number of petri dishes?  Are these the same petri dishes (or whatever experimental units) surveyed over time?  That would mean dealing with repeated measurement analysis which unfortunately *Mathematica* does not do directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform a fit you can use `NonlinearModelFit`.  For example,

```
model = A  Exp[-t/\[Tau]]
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {A, \[Tau]}, t]
bands90[x_] = fit["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> .9];
fromFit = Transpose@{missing, fit /@ missing}
```

I think from `fit` and `bands90` you can construct some meaningful uncertainty estimates. (You could change the confidence level for 1σ uncertainty, for example).

Then we can visualize with the interpolation from my other answer,

```
Show[
    ListPlot[{data, filled, fromFit}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 17, 19, 22, 24}, Automatic}],
    Plot[{fit[t], bands90[t]}, {t, 0, 24}, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}]
]
```

[image]

(The styling can be adjusted, obviously.)

Comment: Rather than post what I have, I upvoted this since it is similar but better. Here is the code I used to get a fit in case it helps. Values and bounds were by eyeball and quite approximate. `data = {{0, 1}, {3, .5}, {6, .85}, {17, .2}, {19, .15}, {22, .2}, {24, .1}};
bnds = {{.7, 1.3}, {.35, .65}, {.45,  1.2}, {0, .4}, {.03, .22}, {0, .4}, {.08, .12}};
func[a_, b_, x_] := a*Exp[-b*x]
constraints = Join[{a > 0, b > 0},Table[bnds[[j, 1]] <= func[a, b, data[[j, 1]]] <= bnds[[j, 2]], {j,7}]];
ff = FindFit[data, {func[a, b, x], constraints}, {a, b}, x]
Out[119]= {a -> 0.827451, b -> 0.0804594}`

Comment: I now realize the data was explicitly available. Better code: `vals = data /. Around[a_, b_] :> a;
bnds = data[[All, 2]] /. Around[a_, b_] :> {a - b, a + b};
func[a_, b_, x_] := a*Exp[-b*x]
constraints = 
  Join[{a > 0, b > 0}, 
   Table[bnds[[j, 1]] <= func[a, b, vals[[j, 1]]] <= bnds[[j, 2]], {j,
      7}]];
ff = FindFit[vals, {func[a, b, x], constraints}, {a, b}, x]

{a -> 0.832239, b -> 0.0789424}` This will show the fit is sort of stretching things, at some data points. `Show[{Plot[func[a, b, x] /. ff, {x, 0, 25}], ListPlot[data]} , 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @Anovice (the interpolation is cubic, not linear.)  One way to understand the comparison is as a *systematic* uncertainty.  Since there is no accessible ground truth and the governing differential equation is only an assumption, you can treat the difference between different fit models as an additional uncertainty.  That the interpolation and fit agree within errors is comforting, of course.  But how seriously you should take it becomes a statistics question, not a Mathematica question :)

Comment: If you want 1σ statistical posterior uncertainties you should use ConfidenceLevel -> 0.68.  But you should have clear eyes about what those uncertainties *mean*.  For example, the red band is much narrower than the known, measured, uncertainties.  So the red band represents something more like "given all of these points, what do I think REALLY happened", rather than "if I had done the experiment in real conditions, I'd have measured a standard deviation of this size."  Obviously the latter can't be true: there are places where you have measurements with larger uncertainties than the fit gives.

Comment: Or, maybe: "given all of these points, if I ran the experiment as many times as I could what would the average behavior be."  Anyway I'd encourage you to look into the statistical methods that are standard in your field.  I'm a scientist, but I'm largely uneducated about typical practices in a biology setting.

Comment: A linear interpolation is _reasonable_, and so is a cubic one.  There is no correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without a definite model one honest thing to do is to just interpolate.  Mathematica's interpolation is order 3 by default, you can set `InterpolationOrder->1` for linear interpolation.

```
f = Interpolation[data]

missing = {9, 15, 18, 21};
filled = Transpose[{missing, f /@ missing}];
ListPlot[{data, filled}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 17, 19, 22, 24}, Automatic}]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Beyond this you get into real science, but you could try fitting the data to some model, getting parameters with uncertainties, and then evaluating the model at the times of interest.

Comment: If you look at the `filled` data it is printed as `{{9, 0.8±0.9}, {15, 0.4±0.5} ...}`, the ±s are the uncertainties.  If you apply `Fullform@filled` you will see it as `Around` expressions.

Comment: For a fit you can use `NonlinearModelFit` though I'm not sure how that interacts with uncertain data.